# r Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I am trying to add arrow heads to a line created by geom_line() in ggplot.
Example:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=(1:2),y=(2:1))
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) +
    geom_line() +
    arrow()
```

The error I get is "Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot".
I found a variety of posts with this error, but they had a complex scenario and the answers called for making what looked like subtle changes in the code.

If instead I run:

```
ggplot(data=cinterval,aes(x=x,y=y))+
    geom_line()
```

I get the expected line.
When I run the expanded code, with a more elaborate plot, I get the error
"Error in as.vector(y) : attempt to apply non-function"

Comment: There's an `arrow` argument to `geom_line` and that's where the `arrow()` function goes to add an arrow head: `ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) +
  geom_line(arrow=arrow())`

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead

```
 library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=(1:2),y=(2:1))
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) +
 geom_line(arrow = arrow(length=unit(0.30,"cm"), ends="first", type ="closed"))
```

Comment: Thank you.  The documentation confused me.